# How to create a basic 2d directional movement method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am new to programming and i want to create a basic 2d directional movement method in javascript. i have a black canvas which is gonna be used as the background, and a white small canvas as a person. i want to be able to make the white canvas move based on arrow keyboard input. and the method is by modifying the top and left margin to make a movement illusion. i need some advise on what should i do and how should i do this, can someone help? :)

here's my html setup

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>main</title>
        <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style media="screen">
            #myCanvas {
                background: black;
            }
            #person {
                background:  white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <div class="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
            
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;"></canvas>
            <canvas id="person" width="8" height="20" style="position: absolute;top: 280px;left: 10px;"></canvas>
            
        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here's the javascript

```
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var person;
    var direction;
    var left = "left";
    var up = "up";
    var right = "right";
    var down = "down";
    var noD = "noD";
    
    var marginTopNow;
    var marginLeftNow;
    
    var rightDirection = false;
    var upDirection = false;
    var rightDirection = false;
    var downDirection = false;
    
    const LEFT_KEY = 37;
    const UP_KEY = 38;
    const RIGHT_KEY = 39;
    const DOWN_KEY = 40;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        person = document.getElementById('person');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        direction = noD;
    }
    
    
    
    function move() {
        if(leftDirection) {
            marginLeftNow -= 1;
        }
        else if(upDirection) {
            marginTopNow -= 1;
        }
        else if(rightDirection) {
            marginLeftNow += 1;
        }
        else if(downDirection) {
            marginTopNow += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you've got what canvases are meant to. Instead of having multiple of them and moving them around via CSS-ish ways, you should probably have a single one and programmatically draw things (sprites) on it. And the code for that is quite different.

Comment: hmm ok, i understand that i have to try different approach on something like this. thanks for the advice :)  , ill try to remake it in a better way.